# Cannot get completed dataset using imputeMCA

Tags: r, imputation

I use missMDA package to fill in multiple categorical columns. However, I cannot get any result from these two functions: estim_ncpMCA(test_fill) and imputeMCA(test_fill). The program keeps running without any progress bar or results popped out.

This is the sample from the dataset.

```r
Hybrid  G1  G5  G8  G9  G10
P1000:P2030 0   -1  0   1   0
P1006:P1384 0   0   0   0   1
P1006:P1401 0   NA  NA  NA  1
P1006:P1412 0   0   0   0   1
P1006:P1594 0   0   0   0   1
P1013:P1517 0   0   0   0   1
```

I am working on a genetic project in R. In this dataset, there are 497 rows and 11,226 columns. Every row is a genetic marker series for a particular hybrid, and every column is a genetic marker ("G1", "G2" and etc) with value 1, 0, -1 and NA. There are total 746,433 of missing values and I am trying to fill in the missing values by imputeMCA.

I also made some transformations on test_fill before running imputeMCA.

```r
test_fill = as.matrix(test_fill)
test_fill[, -1] <- lapply(test_fill[, -1], as.numeric)
```

I am wondering whether this is the result of too many columns in my dataset. And do I need to transpose my columns and rows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found your answer, but I think your function doesn't run because of your first column, which seems to be the label of the individuals. You can specify that it should not be taken into the analysis.

```r
estim_ncpMCA(test_fill[,2:11226], ncp.max = 5) 
imputeMCA(test_fill[,2:11226], ncp = X)
```

I hope this can help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I really appreciate your contribution, we switch to other methods actually.